# Proof and interpretation of $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y, Z] \mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Z]$

Tags: probability, intuition, conditional-probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

First, I understand that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]]$, but

> how to prove that $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y, Z] \mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Z]?$$

Second, for $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]]$, I knew an intuitive interpretation about "*computing an average IQ of a population by first computing the average IQs of men and women respectively and then summing the two averages, with each weighted by the respective rate of men and women*".

> Could you come up with any similar interpretations of the second equation
>   $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y, Z] \mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Z]?$$

Comment: A similar intuition, if say $X$ were IQ, $Y$ were sex and $Z$ were age: the average IQ for a given age is the the average IQ for a given age summed over the sexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything is discrete, the conditional expectation is defined as $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z]=\varphi(Z)$ where
$$
\varphi(z)=\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z=z]=\sum_x x p_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)
$$
with $p_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)=p_{X,Z}(x,z)/p_Z(z)$ for $p_Z(z)>0$ and zero elsewhere.

1. Show that $U:=\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z]$ defined as above is equivalent to requiring that
   $$
   \mathbb{E}[U\mathbf{1}_{Z\in A}]=\mathbb{E}[X\mathbf{1}_{Z\in A}]
   $$
   for all $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.
2. Using the equivalent definition of 1. we thus need to show that
   $$
   \mathbb{E}[V\mathbf{1}_{Z\in A}]=\mathbb{E}[X\mathbf{1}_{Z\in A}]
   $$
   for all $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $V=\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y,Z]$. But this is obvious by using the equivalent definition of $V=\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y,Z]$ since we know that 
   $$
   \mathbb{E}[V\mathbf{1}_{(Y,Z)\in C}]=\mathbb{E}[X\mathbf{1}_{(Y,Z)\in C}]
   $$
   for all $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. Now simply let $C=\mathbb{R}\times A$.

Comment: I am afraid I did not follow you. I am learning basic probability theory which is not axiomatic and I know little about $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: How is $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z]$ defined to you?

Comment: So, are we any closer to a definition of the conditional expectation? @hengxin

Comment: In the elementary probability textbook (I am using), it goes as follows: First, the conditional expected value of $X$ given $Z = z$ is defined as $\mathbb{E}(X \mid Z = z) = \sum_{x} x p_{X \mid Z}(x \mid z)$. Then $\mathbb{E}(X \mid Z)$ is defined as a r.v. evaluated at the r.v. $Z$.

Comment: Then show that this definition of $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z]$ (which is only applicable to random variables who are jointly discrete) is equivalent to requiring that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z];Z^{-1}(A)]=\mathbb{E}[X;Z^{-1}(A)]$ for all (Borel) $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: When $Z = z$ is given, does this equation degenerate to $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]]$? If so, I am coming to understand it.

Comment: I don't follow. Which equation?

Comment: the one I am trying to prove (and understand): $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y, Z] \mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Z]$$

Comment: But $Z=z$ is not given.

Comment: To prove $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y, Z] \mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Z]$$ is to show two functions evaluated on each $Z = z$ are the same. So given $Z = z$, it suffices to prove $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]] = \mathbb{E}[X]$$ which is simpler to prove and easier to understand. Is this argument reasonable?

Comment: No, it's not. You need to show that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y,Z]\mid Z=z]=\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z=z]$ for all $z$ where both conditional expectations are given as a sum according to what you wrote above. That is not equivalent to what you write. I've edited my answer. Maybe you'll find it helpful now.

Comment: I know my mistakes now. Thanks for your help and thanks for your patience.